# Using "Call HTTP web service" to return part of a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm building a Dictionary in SP2013 using the Call HTTP web service action. I've set the URL to:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items?$select=Id, Title
```

This successfully returns all the items in the list 'myList'.

How can I return just some of the items in 'myList'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit items using following operators

`$top`: If you put `$top=50`, query will return you first 50 items. Next 50 items can requested through `__next` URL

`$filter`: specifies which items to return

Let's say you want to get first 50 items from your list. You have to use `$top` like following

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items?$select=Id,Title&$top=50
```

Comment: Thanks Atish. I did managed to find what I need was $filter. However I'm getting a reserved character warning when trying to save: `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('myList')/items?$filter=Title eq [%Variable: Title%]&$select=Id,Title`. Do you know how to set a filter to workflow variable?

Comment: I did not try that yet... You can ask another question for it. I think I have answered your first question.

Comment: I have created URL like `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('myList')/items?$filter=Title eq [%Variable: Title%]&$select=Id,Title` and it did not give any warning. `Title` is string variable. Workflow variable is not the source of your warning I guess